# ReportViewer using an object with a list

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer

I am attempting to create a report using these classes.

```
class purchases
{
    public string purchaser { get; set; }
    public List<date> dates { get; set; }
    public decimal totalCost { get; set; }
}
class date
{
    public List<item> items { get; set; }
    public decimal costForDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime theDate { get; set; }
}
class item
{
    public int itemID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public decimal cost { get; set; }
}
```

The report will ideally look like

```
(header)
Purchases by purchases.purchaser

(report)
date.theDate
    item.itemID      item.name      item.cost
    item.itemID      item.name      item.cost
    item.itemID      item.name      item.cost
    item.itemID      item.name      item.cost
-------------------------------
                        date.costForDate

date .theDate
    item.itemID      item.name      item.cost
    item.itemID      item.name      item.cost
    item.itemID      item.name      item.cost
    item.itemID      item.name      item.cost
-------------------------------
                            date.costForDate

date.theDate
    item.itemID      item.name      item.cost
    item.itemID      item.name      item.cost
    item.itemID      item.name      item.cost
    item.itemID      item.name      item.cost
-------------------------------
                            date.costForDate

-----------------------------------------------------------
Total Cost:                     purchases.totalCost
```

The major problem I have been encountering is telling the rdlc that I want to use a specific purchases object. When I use the report wizard I can choose the purchase class but the lists are separate data sets. This however, will not allow me to choose the specific purchase object I want to use.

I am able to do the report viewer if I just grab directly from a database. The problem is I need to manipulate some of the fields before displaying.